# python: random.random in function always returns 0?

Tags: python, random

I have this function:

```
def get_starting_centroids(centroids,size,num):
    for i in range(0,num):
        temp = []
        for j in range(0,size):
            random.seed(time.clock())
            g = random.random()
            g = g*.85 + .15
            print "random: %i" %g
            temp.append(g)
        centroids.append(temp)
    return centroids
```

print tells me it always returns 0. If I test `random.random()` in the python prompt I get a random value. I don't understand what causes this difference

Comment: Why are you re-seeding `random` each round?

Comment: Also, even if there is a reason to re-seed every time, `random.seed()` (without parameters) [uses the current system time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed) by default anyway.

Comment: Yes, if you call `seed` inside the loop, you're not getting random numbers at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are formatting your random value *to an integer*:

```
print "random: %i" %g
```

This **floors** the value, which is below 1 *always*, so you always end up with `0`.

Print a floating point value:

```
print "random: %.5f" % g
```

and you'll see there are actually values there, just between 0.15 and 1.

You should not seed the random generator every round; if you need to seed, just do it once outside the loop:

```
random.seed()  # seeds to the current system time by default
for j in range(0,size):
    g = random.random()
    g = g*.85 + .15
    print "random: %.5f" % g
    temp.append(g)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for putting up with these kind of questions. Sometimes you just miss the easy stuff. I think you were the first poster so you got it

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the formatting.

Use

```
print "random: %f" %g
```

You are formatting as decimal, which truncates g, which is a float.
g should be added to the temp array correctly, though.